# append iteratively generated td-s to appended tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I'm trying to generate dynamic table with jquery. So stuck on appending in appending. 
Need to write something like this. But of course it have wrong syntax :)

```
  var $tbl = $('<table>').attr('id', 'basicTable');
  $tbl.append($('<tr>').for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){($('<td>')});

$('body').append($tbl);
```

Comment: Don't trust jQuery to properly close you elements, always include the end tag, `$('<table></table>');` and so on.

Comment: @Andrew: Pretty sure it boils down to `document.createElement('table')`, which skips the concept of "end tags" altother.

Comment: @Eric For a simple element yes, but for anything else there is a lot more stuff that goes on, that can be screwed up. I think always do this is a lot simpler rule to remember than, do it this way when it's this kind and do it that way when it's that kind.

Comment: @Andrew: A better rule of thumb is "don't leave jQuery to construct complex document fragments".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var $tr = $('<tr></tr>');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $tr.append('<td></td>');
}
var $tbl = $('<table></table>').attr('id', 'basicTable');
$tbl.append($tr);

$('body').append($tbl);
```

[See here for jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTWhm/).

Comment: +1, although you can cut out the `var i;` line by just using `for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {`...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan jslint doesn't like that since it can obfuscate matters if two loops use the same variable name (as it looks like there's two variables, but really there's only one), obviously doesn't affect this case, but is just how I write my js now!

Comment: thanks ) and how to do so and <tr> was in the for
and it is possible to do so

for(var j=0; j<10; j++){
var $tr = $('<tr></tr>');
}
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $tr.append('<td></td>');
}
var $tbl = $('<table></table>').attr('id', 'basicTable');
$tbl.append($tr);

$('body').append($tbl);

Comment: I first wrote this .. but it does not work and I do not know why.
I need to <tr>  was in the other for 


var $tbl = $('<table>').attr('id', 'basicTable');
       for (var i = 0; i < seatlist.length; i++)
       {
           $tbl.append($('<tr>'));
           var a = $("tr:last");
           for (var j = 0; j < seatlist[i].length; j++)
           {
               a.append($('<td>'));
           }
       }

       $('.drag_cont').append($tbl);
       
   });

Answer (score 1):

This should do it -

```
var cont = [];
for (var i = 0;i<10;i++) cont.push('<td></td>');
var $tbl = $('<table>').attr('id', 'basicTable');
$tbl.append('<tr>' + cont.join('') + '</tr>');
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/yeYWP/

See this question for further methods on adding multiple elements of the same type via jQuery - [How should I add multiple identical elements to a div with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201530/how-should-i-add-multiple-identical-elements-to-a-div-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it with fewer variables:

```
var row = $('<tr />');
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    row.append('<td />');

$('body').append(
    $('<table />').attr('id', 'basicTable').append(row);
);
```