# Is there a way to add x elements as children of a newly created element in a Jquery chained statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, chaining, createelement

I'm using the following:

```
 var topWrapper = $('<div />')
    .addClass( 'table-top-wrapper ui-corner-top ui-body-'+o.wrapperTheme )
    .grid({ grid: this.options.grid })
    .append(container)
    .insertBefore(table);
```

and need to append `x` children to this `div` before calling `.grid`.

Say `x=3` is there a way to append `x` number of child divs to the newly created div element in the chain? Somethingl Like a chainable `for-loop`?

Thanks for insights!

Comment: checkout this article for inserting multiple identical elements: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201530/how-should-i-add-multiple-identical-elements-to-a-div-with-jquery

Comment: Sure, why not just roll your own! Something like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/raUsP/) ??

Comment: Why must it be done in a single chain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an array of elements and append:

```
var x = 3;

var topWrapper = $('<div />')
.addClass( 'table-top-wrapper ui-corner-top ui-body-'+o.wrapperTheme )
.append($.map(new Array(x), function(){
  return $('<div/>');
}))
.grid({ grid: this.options.grid })
.append(container)
.insertBefore(table);
```

Comment: I like this best. Very nice and something I have to remember the next time, I'm sitting on this! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own jQuery extension like this:

```
$.fn.appendMultipleChildren = function(child, repeat) {
    var $this = $(this);
    for (var i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
        $this.append(child.clone());
    }
    return $this;
}
```

then call

```
 var topWrapper = $('<div />')
    .addClass( 'table-top-wrapper ui-corner-top ui-body-'+o.wrapperTheme )
    .grid({ grid: this.options.grid })
    .appendMultipleChildren($('<div />'), 3)
    .append(container)
    .insertBefore(table);
```

**Edit** - and here's a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/eJGxm/

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to do it is to assemble them into a single string and then call `jQuery.html`. This doesnt make the loop chainable though. If you really want to do it you can wrap them in a function:

```
topWrapper = $('<div />')
    .addClass( 'table-top-wrapper ui-corner-top ui-body-'+o.wrapperTheme )
    .html((function(){
       var markup = '';
       for (var i =0; i < 3; i++) {
         markup .= '<div></div>';
       }
       return markup;
    })())
    .grid({ grid: this.options.grid })
    .append(container)
    .insertBefore(table);
```

Personally though i find that harder to read than doing the loop before you make your topWrapper calls.

Comment: Good idea... Have to try everything now!